# Is it possible to have Haskell source files with a different extension?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, hpack

In any of the build tools commonly used in Haskell projects (i.e `stack`, `cabal`, or `hpack`), is it possible to have a source directory which contains source files with a different extension (i.e. other than `*.hs` or `*.lhs`)?

I need to have source files with multiple extensions, such as `*.md.lhs`, or `*.rst.lhs` because the same directly needs to be used by `stack`/`cabal`, but the second extension is meaningful to a custom `shake` script that I'm writing.

It seems that `cabal`/`stack` are ignoring any files with `*.*.lhs`

Comment: You're already listing them in `extra-source-files` and it still ignores?

Comment: A hack might be to list them under `extra-doc-files` instead